# Problem with css3 path in the sub-folder of my pages

Tags: php, css, include

So here today I started to create my future page of my website in (localhost) suddenly to avoid having too many pages in the root of the site so I put small pages like (test.php) in a folder (test), when I go to my site `localhost / site / test / test.php`, no problem except that it does not find the css since it is in the root of the site and not in the folder (test) suddenly I wonder if there is a solution to solve this problem without me being forced to introduce the css / img etc file in the folder (test).

Thank you!

Comment: What is the location of your css file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use ../ in the href attribute to navigate one folder back . To go back 2 levels into the site folder from your test.php file, you'll need 2 of them,  ../../

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use either of the following methods:

1. By using `../` to go back one folder to find css on root folder
   e.g: `href="../css/style.css"`
2. By Using `/` to go to the root folder and find the css file.
    `href="/css/style.css` **or** `href="http://localhost/myproject/css/style.css"`